# Getting string from a Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton that generates the long, lats. I can log them but want to be able to get them. What am I doing wrong?

singleton.h

```
@interface ClassLocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    NSString *lat;
    NSString *longt;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *longt;

+ (ClassLocationManager*) sharedSingleton;
```

singleton.m - the longt, lat strings are given values in the -(id)init

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Latitude : %@",lat);

    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Longitude : %@",longt);
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

codethatcallsthem.m

```
NSString *formatted3 = [[ClassLocationManager sharedSingleton] longt];
NSString *formatted4 = [[ClassLocationManager sharedSingleton] lat];
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your properties don't match your ivar names..

1. EITHER leave the ivars out and use the automatically created ones (_longt, _lat)
2. OR better yet say self.longt = and self.lat =
3. OR bad: use @synthesize to make the properties use the existing ivars

-- i'd go with 2.

Comment: Option 2 returns the value set in (id)init but not the value generated in (void)locationManager.

Comment: lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds]; => self.lat = ... same for longt

Comment: That's what I did - it was a timing issue - I need to work out how to delay the process until it has the result - many thanks.

Comment: yes, that's something else I noticed.. you are trying to make an async procc synchronous. Maybe you could send out a NSNotification when you're ready